# How can I customise a radio button on the right?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use this in my Radio Buttons so the text will be on the left:

```
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
```

But when I do it it uses the android's ugly drawable. Is there a way I can change it to my own customized Radio Button?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: did you try setting your drawable? `android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_drawable"`

Comment: @cosmincalistru How can the android studio know which drawable is for the unchecked and which is for the checked?

Answer (score 0):

The default drawable `btn_radio` is in fact a selector.
For example, the api 15 has for that element this description :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_pressed" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_selected" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

So, to override that you would need a selector that follows the method but uses your own images.